# Как правильно запустить Workerman через SSH?

Tags: php, ssh, workerman

Я использую Codeigniter и Workerman.
В примере на сайте разработчика указан пример запуска сервера:

```
php start.php start
```

Предполагается, что основной файл с кодом запуска находится в корне, но мой файл находится в папке с сайтом в контролере:

```
site.ru/servers/index
```

Я пробовал запускать так:

```
php /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/index.php servers index start
php /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/index.php start index servers
php /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/index.php start servers index
```

Не получается - CI выдает ошибку, а в первом случае получаю

> Unknown command: servers Usage: php yourfile  [mode]

Как правильно запустить?

Comment: `start.php` - не?

Comment: у меня нет в корне файла старта. Код запуска в site.ru/servers/index, так как он в классе контролера, я не могу запустить его, просто указав путь.

Comment: Код `сервера` в студию.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала перейдите в папку, где нужно запустить php процесс

```
$ cd var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/servers/index
$ php start.php start -d
```

В зависимости от того, в какой директории вы находитесь, может меняться путь для `cd`. Просмотреть путь можно написав `ls`. Команда чтобы перейти в корень:

```
$ cd /
```